# What is it called when trying to overload a function based purely on the return type?

Tags: c#

What is it called when trying to overload a function based purely on the return type?

ie:

```
Public String DoWork()

Public int DoWork()
```

You cannot do the above, right?

Is that called covariance?

Comment: It's called a compiler error.

Comment: Well, I think this is simply called "overloading on the return type", which is not allowed by the C# spec but is allowed by the CLR spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, covariance refers to changing the return type when **overriding** not overloading.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)

```
 class A {
 }

 class B extends A {
 }

 // Classes demonstrating method overriding:

 class C {
     A getFoo() {
         return new A();
     }
 }

 class D extends C {
     B getFoo() {
         return new B();
     }
 }
```

Comment: can you give an example of this

Comment: Well, that example is Java, and covariance is not just that. That is "return type covariance in Java".

Comment: The question was not about what covariance is.

Answer (score 5):

It's still called a "method overload" but sometimes you'll hear the more verbose "return-type method overload." It is not possible in C#.

From the C# specification:

> The signature of a method must be unique in the class in which the method is declared. The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the number of type parameters and the number, modifiers, and types of its parameters. The signature of a method does not include the return type.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use generics:

```
public T DoWork<T>()
{
}
```

Edited to fix grammar; the return type doesn't get enclosed in angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Return type is not included in method's signature. That is why you cannot have two methods that differ only by return type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an intermediate type to get this behaviour.  Here's [a way to do it in C++](http://www.codepost.org/browse/snippets/117).  I don't know so much C# but I believe it should support this technique.